# Find IDs and names of students who took CS-101 and did not take CS-319

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Can someone help with this homework problem:

Find IDs and names of students who took CS-101 and did not take
CS-319.

These are the two tables that I can use for this assignment:

```
TAKES (Table)

ID (PK)

course_id (PK)

sec_id (PK)

semester (PK)

year (PK)

grade



STUDENT (Table)

ID (PK)

name

dept_name

tot_cred
```

I tried this but was unable to successfully exclude the students who who took "CS-319"

```
     SELECT ID, name, course_id
     FROM (
          SELECT ID, name, course_id
          FROM student NATURAL JOIN takes
          WHERE course_id != "CS-319") AS T1
     WHERE course_id = "CS-101"
```

Comment: Generally speaking, you never need to use `NATURAL JOIN` in a query.

Comment: You project on rows where id is named n etc & id takes cid etc & cid isn't 319 & is 101. You want to project on rows where id is named n etc & id takes cid etc & cid is 101 & there does not exist a cid where id takes cid & cid is 319. Both parts are faqs. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular formatted initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least three separate ways to solve this problem in SQL.

1. Set operations ( `SELECT` then exclude using `EXCEPT` ).

   - As MySQL doesn't support `EXCEPT` we can use `NOT IN` instead.
2. Anti-join (`LEFT OUTER JOIN`).
3. Join and discriminate on `COUNT`.

### Approach 1: `SELECT` then exclude using `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT
    student_id
FROM
    takes
WHERE
    course_id = 'CS-101'

EXCEPT

SELECT
    student_id
FROM
    takes
WHERE
    course_id = 'CS-319'
```

Then use this as an inner-query to `JOIN` on student information:

```
SELECT
    iq.student_id,
    student.name
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            student_id
        FROM
            takes
        WHERE
            course_id = 'CS-101'

        EXCEPT

        SELECT
            student_id
        FROM
            takes
        WHERE
            course_id = 'CS-319'
    ) AS iq

    INNER JOIN students ON iq.student_id = students.student_id
```

### Approach 1 for MySQL (using `NOT IN`):

```
SELECT
    iq.student_id,
    student.name
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            student_id
        FROM
            takes
        WHERE
            course_id = 'CS-101'
            AND
            student_id NOT IN
            (
                SELECT
                    student_id
                FROM
                    takes
                WHERE
                    course_id = 'CS-319'
            )
    ) AS iq

    INNER JOIN students ON iq.student_id = students.student_id
```

### Approach 2: Anti-join:

```
SELECT
    s.student_id,
    s.name
FROM
    students AS S

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            student_id,
            COUNT(*) AS Cs101Count
        FROM
            takes
        WHERE
            course_id = 'CS-101'
        GROUP BY
            student_id
    ) AS c1 ON s.student_id = c1.student_id

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            student_id,
            COUNT(*) AS Cs319Count
        FROM
            takes
        WHERE
            course_id = 'CS-319'
        GROUP BY
            student_id
    ) AS c2 ON s.student_id = c2.student_id
WHERE
    c1.Cs101Count > 0
    AND
    c2.cS319Count = 0
```

### Approach 3: Join and discriminate on `COUNT`:

```
SELECT
    s.student_id,
    s.name
FROM
    students AS S
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            student_id,
            COUNT( CASE WHEN course_id = 'CS-101' END ) AS Cs101Count,
            COUNT( CASE WHEN course_id = 'CS-319' END ) AS Cs319Count
        FROM
            takes
        GROUP BY
            student_id
    ) AS c ON c.student_id = s.student_id
WHERE
    c.Cs101Count > 0
    AND
    c.Cs319Count = 0
```

### More approaches:

There are other alternatives using `WHERE EXISTS`, `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, and so on. One of the problems (or challenges) when using SQL is there are different ways to query the source data to get the exact same results. Have fun!

Comment: Since it is MySQL `EXCEPT` function is not available so *Approach 1* will not be applicable here.

Comment: @James Thanks for the catch - I've added a version using `NOT IN`.

Comment: The NOT IN solution appears to work. thank you so much.